# MySQL Improve read speed by moving text field to separate table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that is used to lookup a json object (text field) by some criteria

```
id, user_id, json, gender, age, ...
```

I want to retrieve the json in this way:

```
SELECT user_id, json FROM data WHERE gender = 'male' AND age > 25
```

I never query the json textfield itself.

Would it help performance if I move the json field to a separate table?

data

```
id, user_id, json_id, age, gender
```

json

```
id, json
```

Comment: yes, you can improve lookup speed. you are on the right way.

Comment: I'd have the json table store the FK of the data table rather than introducing a new key.